# Read PDF summary with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to read some `PDF` documents with `Python`.

I would like to extract a summary in the first page.

Does it exist a `library` able to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to your problem: first you must extract the text from the PDF, and then run that through a summarizer.

There are many utilities to extract text from a PDF, though text in a PDF may not be stored in a 'logical' order.
*(For instance, a page with two text columns might be stored with the first line of both columns, followed by the next, etc; rather than all the text of the first column, then the second column, as a human would read it.)*

The [PDFMiner library](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/) would seem to be ideal for extracting the text. A quick Google reveals that there are several text summarizer python libraries, though I haven't used any of them and can't attest to their abilities. But parsing human language is tricky - even for humans.

https://pypi.org/project/text-summarizer/

http://ai.intelligentonlinetools.com/ml/text-summarization/

If you're using MacOS, there is a built-in text summarizing Service. Right click on any selected text and click "Summarize" to activate. Though it seems hard to incorporate this into any automated process.

Comment: Sorry, my question was not clear. In the first page of my pdf there is a 'table of contents'. I would like to read it in python.

Comment: @NicoleMorselli Is this just text on the front page; or is it links that take you to the page when you click on it? What OS are you using? Or is the Table of Contents in the PDF metadata (i.e. in the sidebar)?

Comment: it is just text on the front page. I tried to read it with pyPDF2 and put it in a dictionary just by splitting characters from numbers but it is not a robust method. I tried also to read it as a table (with the library tabula) but it's not splitting the columns right.  I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: As said, the order in which text is stored in a PDF file does not necessarily relate to its position or logical readable sequence. If you can get a coherent line, then splitting the final numbers from white space should be easy enough. Can I ask what you're doing with this data? Perhaps there's another way to get your end result.

Comment: I want to split the pdf document into different sections according to the table of contents